# iOS >> Ads Conversion Link: Is there a way to "catch" from which site / banner / ad users got to my app in the App Store?

Tags: ios, app-store, hyperlink, ads

I did some ads to my apps; the only information I get regarding how many people got to my app is from the sites where I advertised (Google, Facebook, etc...); and this is only showing how many people clicked the link.

I want info about the following:

- How many people got to my app page - per each ad that I have
- How many people downloaded the app  - per each ad that I have

Can anyone assist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are talking about is conversion tracking.

There's no easy way because you don't get stats from the app store page itself, so you have to do it like this:

1. when the user clicks your banner, record their device IP address in your database.
2. when they launch your app on their iPhone for the first time, make a call to your website using native code in your app and log the IP address again. If you get a match then you'll know that the user who clicked the banner is the same one who launched the app, therefore they must have just downloaded it from the app store.

It's not perfect because it won't work if there's a long time between them downloading and first launching the app (assuming they don't have a static IP), or if they download the app on a PC and then install it via iTunes later. It should work in a lot of cases though.

Some of the standard analytics packages have this capability already, for example Google/Admob supports tracking a user from clicking an Admob ad to launching the app in this way (Assuming you are using Google analytics in your app):

http://support.google.com/admob/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1704628